# ¿Cómo envío los datos del formulario si el submit se desaibilta al hacer click con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código con jQuery:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-primary").click(function () {
      $("#btn-primary").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#button-spinner").show();
      setTimeout(function () {
        $("#button-spinner").hide();
      }, 50000);
      $("#text-spinner2").show();
      setTimeout(function () {
        $("#button-spinner").hide();
      }, 50000);
      $("#text-spinner").show();
      setTimeout(function () {
        $("#text-spinner").hide();
      }, 50000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Evito que se haga doble click en un formulario, el formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('process') }}" class="submit__prevent--form">@csrf
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-primary" class="submit__prevent--button">
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin auth__spinner"></i>Finalizar la compra
  </button>
</form>
```

AL dar click se el submit si se cambia a disabled, se muestra lo siguiente:

Procesando su compra...

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div id="button-spinner" class="spinner-grow text-primary" style="width: 2rem; height: 2rem; display: none" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only">Procesando su compra...</span>
  </div>
  <span class="h3 text-primary" id="text-spinner" style="display: none">
    <strong>Por favor espere...</strong></span>
  <span class="h4 text-primary" id="text-spinner2" style="display: none">
    <strong>Estamos procesando su compra...</strong></span>
</div>
```

Pero el formulario no se envía, se queda congelada la página, y el formulario no es procesado, ya cambie de attr a prop en ("disabled", true); pero nada de eso funciona, ¿Hay algo más que tenga qué hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu formulario no se esta enviando podría ser porque el evento de enviar se esta evitando, quizá haya algún código que este causando eso en otro lugar, pero puedes hacer que el formulario se envie desde javascript. Le colocas un `id` a la etiqueta `form` y en el js le agregas al final dentro del evento `click` lo siguiente para enviar el formulario `$('#formProcess').submit();`, quedaria de esta manera:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('process') }}" class="submit__prevent--form" id="formProcess">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-primary" class="submit__prevent--button">
        <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin auth__spinner"></i>Finalizar la compra
    </button>
</form>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn-primary").click(function() {
            $("#btn-primary").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#button-spinner").show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#button-spinner").hide();
            }, 50000);
            $("#text-spinner2").show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#button-spinner").hide();
            }, 50000);
            $("#text-spinner").show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#text-spinner").hide();
            }, 50000);
            $('#formProcess').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono, me podrías decir por favor ¿Que hace esto  $('#formProcess').submit();?

Comment: El método submit() ejecuta el evento para enviar un formulario, básicamente hace la misma acción que al presionar un botón tipo submit dentro de un formulario, pero desde JavaScript, se suele utilizar cuando se quita la funcionalidad por defecto de un evento para hacerla personalizada

Comment: Muchas gracias, saludos claro y bien explicado tu comentario.

Comment: De nada @Nemachtilli